# MAUI How to force SfExpander to resize height

Tags: maui, syncfusion, expander

In Maui at my Syncfusion expander (SfExpander) I have custom view (SeVoView) and I set the visibility by a property.
The visibility changes after rendering the expander and the view is shown inside the expander, but the height of the expander is not extended by the inserted view. This cuts off the lowest content.

**How can I get the expander to recalculate and render its height?**

```xml
<expander:SfExpander IsExpanded="True">
    <expander:SfExpander.Header>
        <custom:PointerStackLayout>
            <Border Style="{StaticResource ExpanderHeader}">
                <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                        <FormattedString>
                            <Span Text="{x:Static localization:AppResources.MyHeader}" />
                        </FormattedString>
                    </Label.FormattedText>
                </Label>
            </Border>
        </custom:PointerStackLayout>
    </expander:SfExpander.Header>

    <expander:SfExpander.Content>
        <VerticalStackLayout >
            <!-- skipped elements -->
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <!-- skipped elements -->
                <Frame >
                    <VerticalStackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding TopGroups}">
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:TopGroup">
                                <Grid >
                                    <!-- skipped elements -->
                                    <VerticalStackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Tops}">
                                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Top">
                                                    <sitzung:SeVoView Top="{Binding}"
                                                                      IsVisible="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:SePageViewModel}, Mode=FindAncestorBindingContext}, Path= IsOnline}"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                   </VerticalStackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </expander:SfExpander.Content>
</expander:SfExpander>
```

Comment: You have a lot of redundant layout nesting levels inside of the `SfExpander.Content`. Have you tried reducing the nesting by removing the two outer *VerticalStackLayout*s as well as the *Grid* in the DataTemplate? This should already remove load from the layout engine. Apart from that, it might just be a bug in SfExpander. Have you tried other expander controls?

Comment: @Julian I have removed UI elements that are not relevant to this problem (for example, various labels). This is where the many nested elements come from.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the clarification. It may be helpful to add a comments like `<!-- skipped elements -->` or something similar to those parts of the example code for other readers.

Comment: @Julian I tried the community toolkit expander and are getting the same result (no resizing after showing the custom view).

Comment: Maybe try this one then: https://github.com/ewerspej/epj.Expander.Maui. Generally, there still are some resizing issues in MAUI when the content of views change in certain situations, which is quite annoying.